# ImageView adjustViewBounds does not work properly on Xamarin.Android

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, android-imageview

I'm using the adjustViewBounds property on an ImageView like:

```
<ImageView
android:id="@+id/rotImage"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignParentLeft="false"
android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
android:layout_alignParentTop="false"
android:layout_centerVertical="true"
android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
android:maxHeight="60dp"
android:maxWidth="60dp"
android:adjustViewBounds="true" />
```

I'm setting my ImageView like follows:

```
Bitmap image = Base64Converter.Base64ToBitmap(stringimage);
imageview.SetImageBitmap(image);
```

My problem is that my ImageView is empty, just white.
If I delete the adjustViewBounds property the image is shown but not as I wish.

My Xamarin Version: last stable (4.2.2.11)

Answer (score 1):

adjustViewBounds might not play well with your layout. I would try using scaleType instead, I would start off trying FIT_CENTER, but it depends on what you want to achieve.

Comment: I tried using scaleType. It's not what I want but I have to use some hacking to get what I want thank you!